# Building specific project in a solution using Azure devops without yaml

Tags: c#, azure-devops, octopus-deploy

My solution consists of multiple projects, I'm trying to build a single project(windows Project) among that solution using MSBuild and trying to generate an .exe file and publish an artifact in Azure DevOps. I tried to build the specific project using MSBuild task on Azure pipelines but it was throwing and it is throwing an error 'MSBuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
in existing project i have added a new windows scheduler.
only one sln file i have for all the projects.
Can you please advice if i am using the correct configuration . Or i might i have to create a new sln file for windows project?
click on the link to open the images.

[solution structure]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trtju.png

[pipeline congiguration] :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH8px.png

[error in pipeline]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5vxQ.png

i have added a new windows scheduler in existing project and tried creating a separate pipeline for this new project but doesnot worked
i have tried couple of steps but didnot worked.
after following all the steps still hit the error attaching the screen shots.
**now able to build but artifact didnot copied**
[pipeln](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLrOS.png):
[artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plZek.png):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide the correct complete relative path of the project file (**`.csproj`**) to the [VSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines).

In the **Solution** field on the VS Build task, you should fill in the path "**`OSMart.WindowsService\OSMart.WindowsService.csproj`**".

---

**EDIT_1:**

In addition, when you want to build a particular project within a solution, it is recommended using [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/msbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines).

[image]

If you project is .NET Core, you also can use the [.NET Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to building the projects via '**`dotnet build`**' command.

---

**EDIT_2:**

You can add a Bash task to run the following command line before the MSBuild task.

```bash
ls -R
```

This command will list all the files under the current working directory. You can use it to check:

- Whether the project files have been successfully checked out and existing under the working directory.
- If the project files are existing, you can get the correct relative paths of the files. Use the correct relative paths to the MSBuild task.

---

**EDIT_3:**

Reference my sample below to configure your pipeline. I have tested this sample, and it can work as expected.

1. The file tree in my TFVC repo.

   [image]
2. Set Get Source in the pipeline.

   [image]
3. Set the MSBuild task to build the specified project.

   [image]

---

**EDIT_4:**

Try to set your pipeline following the images below:

1. Set "**Get sources**" like as below.

   [image]
2. Set the value of '**Project**' field on MSBuild task like as below. And in your TFVC repo, ensure the '**`OSMart.WindowsService.csproj`**' file is existing under the '**`OSMart.WindowsService`**' folder.

   [image]

For "**`MSBuild Arguments`**":

- If you have set the related properties in the **`.csproj`** file. The MSBuild will apply the properties set in the **`.csproj`** file by default.
- If some properties are not set in the **`.csproj`** file, the MSBuild will apply the system default values.
- If you want to overwrite some properties set in the **`.csproj`** file or the system default properties, or you want to set some extra properties, you can set them in the "**`MSBuild Arguments`**" field on the MSBuild task.

---

Comment: thanks for answering , btw i tried this but didnot work.

Comment: @PraweenKumar, See the update in my answer.

Comment: i have added a msbuild task ,  but still getting same error .  ##[error]$\OSMart\Development\OSMart.WindowsService\OSMart.WindowsService.csproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The target "OSMart.WindowsService" does not exist in the project.
Projec

Comment: @PraweenKumar, See the new update (**EDIT_2**) in my answer.

Comment: i dont know if i am using the correct configuration but still error.##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.
F

Comment: in Script path i am using :$/OSMart/Development/OSMart.WindowsService/OSMart.WindowsService.csproj  , Argument :

Comment: @PraweenKumar, Just directly execute '**`ls -R`**' command line without extra arguments under the default working directory.

Comment: ##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\Software\TFSBuildAgent\_work\44\s\ls 'D:\Software\TFSBuildAgent\_work\44\s''
Fini

Comment: @PraweenKumar, Show how you set the bash task to run the command line.

Comment: under the script path i am using the ls -R command.

Comment: @PraweenKumar, I have updated my answer with a sample (see **EDIT_3**). Reference this sample to configure your pipeline.

Comment: followed the same steps but still i am getting an issue i have added the image above please check and let me know if i am doing it correctly. error msg.. Build started 12/13/2023 5:31:17 PM.
##[error]OSMart.ExternalWrapper\OSMart.ExternalWrapper.csproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The target "OSMart.WindowsService" does not exist in the project.

Comment: @PraweenKumar, Show the file tree in your TFVC repo and ensure the target **`.csproj`** file is existing in the TFVC repo.

Comment: i have added the screen shot of repo structure with name repo and repo1 please check. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: @PraweenKumar, From the images you provided, I cannot see '**`OSMart.WindowsService.csproj`**' file is existing.

Comment: @PraweenKumar, Is '**`OSMart.WindowsService.csproj`**' is a dependency of '**`OSMart.ExternalWrapper.csproj`**'? If so, when you build '**`OSMart.ExternalWrapper.csproj`**', you may also need to build '**`OSMart.WindowsService.csproj`**' at first.

Comment: by mistake i have pointed to OSMart.ExternalWrapper.csproj , sorry . corrected it check repo2-windowsdir link. but error still persists "The target "OSMart.WindowsService" does not exist in the project."

Comment: please check my agent job , scree shot attached

Comment: could you please let me know if i have to specify Msbuild arguements on Msbuild task.

Comment: @PraweenKumar, See the latest update (**`EDIT_4`**) in my answer.

Comment: Thanks now i am able to build the pipeline , however i am not able to copy the artifact "##[warning]Directory 'D:\a\8\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.
Finishing: Publish Artifact: drop
"

Comment: added artifact link

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned csproj instead of sln in second screenshot.

Comment: if i put sln file it will build entire application , but i want to build only windows project